# Не устанавливается pygame

Tags: python, pip

При попытке установить pygame вылезает это

```
(venv) PS D:\python_game> pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [61 lines of output]
      
      
      WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
      Using WINDOWS configuration...
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zkdvtzdm\pygame_2ad8ae2f071d43818e6a09b0281df62e\setup.py", line 359, in <module>
          buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zkdvtzdm\pygame_2ad8ae2f071d43818e6a09b0281df62e\buildconfig\config.py", line 225, in main
          deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zkdvtzdm\pygame_2ad8ae2f071d43818e6a09b0281df62e\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 497, in main
          and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zkdvtzdm\pygame_2ad8ae2f071d43818e6a09b0281df62e\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 290, in ask
          update(x86=x86, x64=x64)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zkdvtzdm\pygame_2ad8ae2f071d43818e6a09b0281df62e\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 273, in update
          download_prebuilts(download_dir, x86=x86, x64=x64)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zkdvtzdm\pygame_2ad8ae2f071d43818e6a09b0281df62e\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 124, in download_prebuilts
          download_sha1_unzip(url, checksum, temp_dir, 1)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zkdvtzdm\pygame_2ad8ae2f071d43818e6a09b0281df62e\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 54, in download_sha1_unzip
          response = urllib.urlopen(request).read()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\пайтон\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
          return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\пайтон\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
          response = meth(req, response)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\пайтон\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
          response = self.parent.error(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\пайтон\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
          return self._call_chain(*args)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\пайтон\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
          result = func(*args)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\пайтон\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
          raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
      urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
      Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip ed561079ec622b0bab5a9e02976f5d540b0622da
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip 137f86474691f4e12e76e07d58d5920c8d844d5b
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip 1436df41ebc47ac36e02ec9bda5699e80ff9bd27
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip 9097148f4529cf19f805ccd007618dec280f0ecc
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.pygame.org/ftp/jpegsr9d.zip ed10aa2b5a0fcfe74f8a6f7611aeb346b06a1f99

      ---
      For help with compilation see:
          https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
      To contribute to pygame development see:
          https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
      ---

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: `пайтон` — переименуйте, чтобы имя каталога содержало только латиницу (и цифры при необходимости).

Comment: Версия питона ?

Comment: ilya484, версия 11. Я уже устранил проблему, нужно было скачать десятую версию